# Change the Querystring?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Goal:
Display the url address as "http://localhost:49332/Home/Contact2/1?idd=first" (except "http://localhost:49332") instead of "http://localhost:49332/Home/Contact2/1?one=second&two=yes"(except "http://localhost:49332") when you have pressed the button Create

Problem:
I don't know how to do it? I strongly believe that it has to do with querystring.

Info:
*I would like the querystring to take place inside of the method "Public ActionResult contact2(int? id, string one, string two)"
*You can download the source code on website (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B23pYZkpAyafbEtYTjhYaHhtNkk/view).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in your case, the easiest way to do this is using the AttributeRouting.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

Or else, you should configure the routes inside RoutConfig class, this link might be helpful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

If you want to use only querystring, just put the action parameter name in the url... everything should work fine.